# Scalafmt config for breaking line on ~> operator

Tags: scala, akka-stream, scalafmt

I want add an option to my *.scalafmt.conf* that would break lines exceeding *maxColumn* length on operator `~>` (edge operator from akka-streams).

Does anyone know if this is even an option and if yes, how to achieve it?

Thanks!